# Python3 print (something, flush=True) only working on localhost, get buffered externally

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache, printing, flush

I have this python test script to print realtime to my webpage. When I run it locally, it it runs well (http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.py), but if I run it from another computer, it gets buffered and the whole page waits until completion. 
Here's the snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time

print ("Content-type: text/html\n\n", flush=True)

for i in range(10):
    print (i, flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

I tested it on two machines and both behave the same:
server1: vm, Centos 7, Apache 2.4, Python 3.6
server2: physical, Fedora28, Apache 2.4, Pyhon 3.6

What can I do to "stream" it to external computers?